# For Loop or while loop SQL consecutive dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that tells us the date something ran and if it failed or not.
I need a query that will get the last failed date and then the last consecutive date that it failed, so basically the starting date of the failure to the end date of the failures where the dates are consecutive in between.

Table

```
   EntityID |    Date     | Entities | Loaded | Status |
    B0034     2017-11-16       54       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-16       54       full    Success
    B0034     2017-11-15       54       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-15       58       full    Failed   
    B0035     2017-11-15       88       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-14       56       full    Failed
    B0036     2017-11-15       50       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-13       56       full    Failed
    B0037     2017-11-15       50       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-12       34       full    Success
    B0034     2017-11-14       50       full    Success
    B0035     2017-11-14       38       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-11       50       full    Success
    B0037     2017-11-14       59       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-10       11       full    Failed
    B0037     2017-11-13       67       full    Success
    B0037     2017-11-12       78       full    Success
    B0033     2017-11-09       32       full    Failed
    B0033     2017-11-08       99       full    Failed 
    B0033     2017-11-17       33       full    Success
```

in this case For ID B0033 I would need:

```
  EntityID |    Date     | Entities | Loaded | Status |
    B0033     2017-11-15       58       full    Failed  
    B0033     2017-11-13       56       full    Failed
```

As B0033 Failed consecutively from the 13th to the 15th

Sample DDL as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (EntityID varchar(5),
                      [Date] date,
                      [Entities] int,
                      Loaded varchar(4),
                      [Status] varchar(7));

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
    ('B0034','20171116',54,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171116',54,'full','Success'),
    ('B0034','20171115',54,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171115',58,'full','Failed'),  
    ('B0035','20171115',88,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171114',56,'full','Failed'),
    ('B0036','20171115',50,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171113',56,'full','Failed'),
    ('B0037','20171115',50,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171112',34,'full','Success'),
    ('B0034','20171114',50,'full','Success'),
    ('B0035','20171114',38,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171111',50,'full','Success'),
    ('B0037','20171114',59,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171110',11,'full','Failed'),
    ('B0037','20171113',67,'full','Success'),
    ('B0037','20171112',78,'full','Success'),
    ('B0033','20171109',32,'full','Failed'),
    ('B0033','20171108',99,'full','Failed'),
    ('B0033','20171117',33,'full','Success');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;
GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY Date ASC) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, [Status] ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Grp
    FROM #Sample),
TopBottom AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, Grp ORDER BY Date ASC) AS RNAsc,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, Grp ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RNDesc,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY Grp DESC) AS Ranking
    FROM Groups
    WHERE [Status] = 'Failed')
SELECT EntityID,
       [Date],
       Entities,
       Loaded,
       [Status]
FROM TopBottom
WHERE (RNAsc = 1 OR RNDesc = 1)
  AND Ranking = 1;
```

Comment: Looks like this is doing it! thanks.. I barely even understand what is going on with this query but it looks like it works.

Comment: The idea is called Groups and Islands. The first CTE puts your data into groups based on their EntityID and [status]. Consecutive statuses for the same entity are placed in the same group (this achieved by one ROW_NUMBER() being subtracted from the other). In the next CTE, as you need to top and bottom rows, I use ROW_NUMBER() again to give the last and first rows a row number of 1. The DENSE_RANK is used to determine which grp, for that EntityID is the latest (hence why DENSE_RANK and not RANK). This is where I also filter to Failed. Finally, just return the rows with ranks/row numbers of 1.

Comment: We are looking to get this into an easier to read table:
where the Entity ID is on one row and the 2 dates are on the same row. instead of a separate row for each date  and further help would be great!

EntityID |    Date_From    |    Date_to    | Entities | Loaded | Status |
    B0033     2017-11-13    2017-11-15        58       full    Failed

Comment: I'll need a little more info. You have Entities, but the value changed (it was 56 at the start, and 58 at the end). What should be displayed?

Comment: Sorry Entities does not need to be included basically just need to know the EntityID and the 2 dates for each group in one row

Answer (score 1):

For the OP's other request in the above comments (to my initial answer). This should get you what you want. Mind that this only returns one values for entities. You *should* be able to work out how to change this for your needs otherwise though.

```
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY Date ASC) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, [Status] ORDER BY Date ASC) AS Grp
    FROM #Sample),
Latest AS (
    SELECT *,
           MIN([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp) As Start_Date,
           MAX([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp) As End_Date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RN
    FROM Groups
    WHERE [Status] = 'Failed')
SELECT EntityID,
       Start_Date, End_Date,
       Entities,
       Loaded,
       [Status]
FROM Latest
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Tried this it is giving me the format i want but the dates are not correct as they were in the previous query you hooked me up with. It seems the MIN date is the Min for the whole table, not from the groups we put them into in the first query.

Comment: @catalyph it's not that I don't believe you, but that's not the result I get for the sample data I have. That SQL, above, provides a `Start_Date` of `2017-11-13` and an `End_Date` of `2017-11-15` for `EntityID` `B0033` using the table `#Sample` in your initial post.

Answer (score 0):

This I what ended up being the query I used purely based on Larnu's help!

```
WITH Groups AS(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID  ORDER BY run_date DESC) - 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, [load_status] ORDER BY run_date DESC) AS Grp
FROM run_history),
Loaded as (SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, Grp ORDER BY run_date DESC) AS RNDesc,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID, Grp ORDER BY run_date ASC) AS RNAsc,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY grp ASC) AS Ranking
FROM Groups 
WHERE Load_status = 'Failed'),
Piv as (SELECT *
FROM Loaded
WHERE (RNAsc = 1 OR RNDesc = 1) and (Ranking = 1))
SELECT distinct EntityID,
       MIN([run_date]) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID) As [Start_Date],
       MAX([run_date]) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID) As End_Date,
       load_status
FROM Piv
```